# C - Acces argument vector create pointer & read value

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to make a pointer of the argument vector and read the value from it. 
This doesn't work as expected. Here's the current code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char *ptr_to_a;

   if(argc != 3)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   char* argumentA = argv[1];
   char* argumentB = argv[2];

   ptr_to_a = &argumentA;


   printf("First argument is %s \n", argumentA);
   printf("Second argument is %s \n", argumentB);

   printf("Memory address of ptr_to_a is %p \n", ptr_to_a);
   printf("Memory address of argumentA is %p \n", &argumentA);

   printf("First argument through pointer is %s \n", *ptr_to_a);



   return 0;
}
```

The output from this code is as next

```
First argument is hello 
Second argument is world 
Memory address of ptr_to_a is 0x7fff5744cb80 
Memory address of argumentA is 0x7fff5744cb80 
First argument through pointer is ?
```

What am I doing wrong :?

Comment: So _what_ do you expect ?

Comment: And don't ignore the compiler warnings.

Comment: `argumentA` is `char*`, so `&argumentA` is `char**`. But you assigned it to `ptr_to_a`, which is `char*`.

Comment: And the argument corresponding to `%s` must be `char*`. `*ptr_to_a` is `char`.

Comment: You probably just want `char *ptr_to_a;`-> `char **ptr_to_a;`.

Comment: I except the result "hello". if I change char* ptr_to_a to void* ptr_to_a and cast it in the printf to * (char *) ptr_to_a I do not get errors form the compiler, but still not the output "hello".

Comment: @MichaelWalz the char **ptr_to_a made it. Could you explain why's that?

Comment: @Zhendos `void*` doesn't change much (In fact, it makes it worse since you can't dereference a void pointer). `char **ptr_to_a;` declares a pointer to pointer and when you dereference it (in printf) you get a pointer `char*` which is a pointer to your 2nd argument.

Answer (score 3):

`&argumentA` is a pointer to pointer (`char**`) which you are assigning to `ptr_to_a` which a `char*`. So, there's a type mismatch in this assignment:

```
ptr_to_a = &argumentA;
```

Change the type of `ptr_to_a` to `char**`:

```
   char **ptr_to_a;
```